# Run ansible command in not target hostname

Tags: ansible

I have these servers:

- `ansible01`
- `server01`
- `server02`
- `nagios01`

And I want to run these tasks from `ansible01`:

1. `nagios01:/scripts/desmonitor {{inventory_hostname}}` # For disabling Nagios for each server in playbook.
2. Run tasks in `server01` & `server02`.

How can I do the task 1 in a playbook? (Use all the time a not target hostname, in this case: `nagios01`).
I'm trying:

```
- name: Disable Nagios
  command: "/scripts/desmonitor {{inventory_hostname}}"
  delegate_to: nagios01
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see you're trying a task, but I don't see how it's not working. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably something like this?

```
- name: Disable Nagios
  command: "/scripts/desmonitor {{ item }}"
  delegate_to: nagios01
  loop:
    - server01
    - server02
```